# how to set Linear layout child's height as tallest child height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four `textviews` in my `Linear Layout` and they have equal
width as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView86" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is, The textviews should be displayed with the same height.The content(text) for that textview will be set programmatically. I tried with `Relative layout` but the `width` of textview couldn't be same. I need **both height and width should be same as tallest child**.

Guide me please. Thanks!

Comment: Give full code your layout. You can use in parent layout  layout_weight to get the result .

Comment: Do you want textxtview to horizontally allign or Vertically ?

Comment: Like, In a single row ,they should be displayed with same height and width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/black_30"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/tw__composer_red"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! simply changing the height to "match_parent" works. :)

Comment: Thats how LinearLayout react to the child views .

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below xml Code , You set the child height to `wrap_content` that should be `match_parent` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/bluebackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView86" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/bluebackground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/bluebackground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/bluebackground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/bluebackground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```