# ConstraintLayout equal height and width of textviews with drawable image and different texts

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to replicate the below LinearLayout parent and child views to ConstraintLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.xyz.constraintlayout.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Section Number" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_not_interested_black_48dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="Book of first_text Language"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_not_interested_black_48dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="Book of second_text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/third_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_not_interested_black_48dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="Book of third_text Topics and Miscellaneous"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the output is:

[LinearLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhBM3.png)

I tried to replicate to ConstraintLayout with spread chains as below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.sed.constraintlayout.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Section Number"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_not_interested_black_48dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:text="Book of first_text Language"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second_text"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/section_label"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_not_interested_black_48dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:text="Book of second_text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/third_text"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/section_label"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/third_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_not_interested_black_48dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:text="Book of third_text Topics and Miscellaneous"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/second_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/section_label"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="first_text, second_text, third_text" />
```

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
The output is:

[ConstraintLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Pwj.png)

As it is evident that the height of the views in the constraint layout is not even.
How to make it even?
Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I added barrier to the layout as suggested by @StarterPack but still the same output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConstraintLayout: set height of all views in row to match the tallest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288173/constraintlayout-set-height-of-all-views-in-row-to-match-the-tallest-one)

Comment: @StarterPack, Thanks, I updated my code with barriers but couldn't see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

[image]> Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Section Number"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Book of first_text Language"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/second_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/section_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Book of second_text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/first_text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/third_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/first_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/third_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Book of third_text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/second_text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/second_text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It seems you have removed the chains, is it even possible to make group of  views have equal height and width without chains? I tried your code but did not get the desired results.

Answer (score -2):

Hint:

- The `layout_height` you given for the three `TextView`'s are
  `wrap_content`.
- If you apply `match_parent` then you can get even `height` but these
  three `TextView` will occupy the complete space.
- Hope you know that the height of the `TextView` will extend depend upon
  the content size in it.
- You can achieve the design what you want by assign same **hardcore

  height** value (like `120dp`) for that three `TextView`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As you suggested if I hardcoded the height say, to 150dp for all views their height became even. However I want to know if there is a way to achieve this without hardcoded values like I did in the LinearLayout example in my question where I gave match_parent for all views

Comment: Ya in LinearLayout sample height as "match_parent" of TextView  take the height of its parent which is already a "wrap_content"

Comment: Yes, with the help of Guidelines I was able to achieve the result I needed. I created a horizontal guideline below the tallest text view and linked the bottom constraint of all views to the guideline thus making the height even. Thanks once again

Comment: Great.due to lack of time I couldn't try the code,  but with the hint you made it... Thanks for the explanation +1