# Alignment/wrapping inside the ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 3 text views placed horizontally. Leftmost one and rightmost one are of fixed size, but middle one can vary in length significantly. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:text="LEFT"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RIGHT"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/message"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This results in following layout:

[image: very long message]

But if we have short text in the middle, like this:

```
tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"
```

it will look:

[image: short message]

Rightmost view is "glued" to the end.

I want it to follow the middle view, like this:

[image: desired layout]

How can it be achieved?

Comment: what do you mean "follow"? you want to make left one and right one same height like middle one? check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288173/constraintlayout-set-height-of-all-views-in-row-to-match-the-tallest-one?rq=1

Comment: @Kirguduck The height does not matter, "follow" means left gravity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` for the middle view and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"`. Also don't forget to set `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"` for the first view to align the whole layout to the start of the screen. Here how the whole layout should look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="LEFT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/message"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/apply_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/apply_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/message"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image: short]

[image: full]

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a challenge. AFAIK, To do what you want, you have to change the width of the middle TextView to wrap_content and remove right TextView constraint with parent's right.

You could try something like calculating width of left and right then if the total width of the device is more than or equal left + right + middle then you switch from
[image]

to this

[image]