# Forcing uniform button size in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I have a `ConstraintLayout` containing a number of elements, including several buttons in a grid layout. Here is a simplified version of the layout (the actual layout includes additional elements):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want the sizes of the buttons to satisfy two conditions:

1. Each button should contain all its text, without any of it being cut off or ellipsized
2. All the buttons should be the same size

In other words, the size of each button should be equal to the size of the largest text of any button. Is it possible to do this in a `ConstraintLayout`?

I can satisfy the first condition by setting (as in the above XML) the button widths and heights to `odp` and `wrap_content` respectively, and this works for the specific case where all the button texts are the same size (as in the above XML, and in the original (English) version of my app), but when they are not (as happens if, e.g., `Button 4 plus several extra words` is substituted for `Button 4`, and as occurs in at least one of the translations of my app), then the button sizes and alignments lose their symmetry and evenness.

I'd like to stick with `ConstraintLayout`, preferably without nesting another layout inside it, since this seems to be the recommended way to do things today, but I suppose I can switch if I have to. I've tried some of the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288173/constraintlayout-set-height-of-all-views-in-row-to-match-the-tallest-one), but I couldn't get them to work in my case, and as I said, I would really rather stick to a pure `ConstraintLayout` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For want of a better solution, I've decided to just set both the heights and the widths of all the buttons to `0dp` (`MATCH_CONSTRAINT`), which allocates all the available space to the buttons and ensures that they'll all be large enough for whatever text appears in them.